# PostGIS: transform: couldn't project point: latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying following query:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.7104 90.4074)',4326),26986),
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(55.75222 37.61556)', 4326),26986)
);
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (23.7104 90.4074 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)
```

Still I could not understand what am I doing wrong?

But it works:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)',4326),26986),
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1260 42.45)', 4326),26986));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to flip the axis order to (X Y) or (long lat).

90.4074 is beyond the limit for latitude, which is +/- 90°